# Error looping Bitmap class to convert base64 strings into images

Tags: java, android, json, bitmap, android-volley

I wrote a web service in Java -- what I am trying to do is to read JSON data in Android. The problem is, I receive an error **only** when looping the `Bitmap` class. I have the enclosed JSON request code:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest( Request.Method.GET, URL,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    try{
                        // Loop through the array elements
                        for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){

                            JSONObject jsonData = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            String name = jsonData.getString("name");
                            String manufacture = jsonData.getString("manufacture");
                            Double price = Double.valueOf(jsonData.getString("price"));
                            String imageString = jsonData.getString("image");

                            // Display the formatted json data in text view
                            productDetails.append("Name: " + name +"\nManufacture: " + manufacture + "\nPrice: " + price.toString() );
                            productDetails.append("\n\n");

                            // decode base64 string to image
                            decodeImageString( imageString, prodImageButton);

                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        Toast.makeText( getApplication(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    // Do something when error occurred
                    //Toast.makeText( getApplication(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    // Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

private void decodeImageString(String imageString, ImageButton imageView){

    byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode (imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(decoded);
}
```

The error thrown:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: lagecy.live.desh.com.shoppincarttest, PID: 5224
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
                  at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
                  at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
                  at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:118)
                  at lagecy.live.desh.com.shoppincarttest.MainActivity.decodeImageString(MainActivity.java:106)
                  at lagecy.live.desh.com.shoppincarttest.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:31)
                  at lagecy.live.desh.com.shoppincarttest.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:84)
                  at lagecy.live.desh.com.shoppincarttest.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:61)
                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
                  at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Sample JSON data:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Albany",
    "manufacture": "Albany Superior Low Gi Sliced Brown Seed Bread 700g",
    "price": 15.49,
    "category": "Food",
    "type": "Breads",
    "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,...[long text string]"
}]
```

Comment: Remove "data:image/jpeg;base64," from your imageString first, It is not the part of base64

Comment: Your input is not a valid Base-64 string, try your Base-64 string on this website first:
https://www.opinionatedgeek.com/codecs/base64decoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Base64.decode won't be able to decode it, So it has to be removed from your encoded String:

```
final String encodedString = "data:image/jpg;base64, ....";                        
final String pureBase64Encoded = encodedString.substring(encodedString.indexOf(",")  + 1);
```

Now the pureBase64Encoded object is ready to be decoded:

```
 final byte[] decodeString= Base64.decode(pureBase64Encoded, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(decoded);
```

Comment: The code works but it loops and shows only the last converted image, how do I go about looping and display all images?

Comment: Make ArrayList and add in your response loop and set to your adapter

Comment: you need to make recyclerview or listview for showing all images. right now you are parsing your response and convert base64 to bitmaps inside that but not add in any ArrayList or any other data structure. so by default response loop it is execute up to its size and at that time image also convert into bitmap and set that imageview but point is that when loop comes at end for execute last iteration it is also execute and update that imageview so you need to add converted bitmap in the arraylist and set it to adapter.

Answer (score 0):

> Updated codes

```
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest( Request.Method.GET, URL,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    try{
                        // Loop through the array elements
                        for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonData = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            String name = jsonData.getString("name");
                            String manufacture = jsonData.getString("manufacture");
                            Double price = Double.valueOf(jsonData.getString("price"));
                            String imageString = jsonData.getString("image");


                            final String pureBase64Encoded = imageString.substring(imageString.indexOf(",") + 1);

                            // Display the formatted json data in text view
                            productDetails.append("Name: " + name + "\nManufacture: " + manufacture + "\nPrice: " + price.toString());
                            productDetails.append("\n\n");

                            productImages.add(i, pureBase64Encoded);

                            String prodImages = productImages.get(i).toString();


                            // decode base64 string to image
                            decodeImageString( prodImages, prodImageButton);


                        }

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        Toast.makeText( getApplication(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    // Do something when error occurred
                    //Toast.makeText( getApplication(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    // Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

private void decodeImageString(String imageString, ImageButton imageView){

    byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode (imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(decoded);

}
```